# Pandas: sum values in some column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, aggregate

I need to group elements and sum it with one column.

```
   member_id    event_path  event_duration
0        111        vk.com               1
1        111   twitter.com               4
2        111  facebook.com              56
3        111        vk.com              23
4        222      vesti.ru               6
5        222  facebook.com              23
6        222        vk.com              56
7        333      avito.ru               8
8        333       avito.ru               4
9        444       mail.ru               7
10       444        vk.com              20
11       444     yandex.ru              40
12       111     vk.com                 10
13       222     vk.com                 20
```

And I want no unify `member_id` and `event_path` and sum `event_duration`.
Desire output

```
       member_id    event_path  event_duration
0        111        vk.com              34
1        111   twitter.com               4
2        111  facebook.com              56
4        222      vesti.ru               6
5        222  facebook.com              23
6        222        vk.com              76
7        333      avito.ru               12
9        444       mail.ru               7
10       444        vk.com              20
11       444     yandex.ru              40
```

I use

```
df['event_duration'] = df.groupby(['member_id', 'event_path'])['event_duration'].transform('sum')
```

but I get

```
   member_id    event_path  event_duration
0        111        vk.com              34
1        111   twitter.com               4
2        111  facebook.com              56
3        111        vk.com              34
4        222      vesti.ru               6
5        222  facebook.com              23
6        222        vk.com              76
7        333      avito.ru              12
8        333      avito.ru              12
9        444       mail.ru               7
10       444        vk.com              20
11       444     yandex.ru              40
12       111        vk.com              34
13       222        vk.com              76
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `groupby` with parameters `sort=False` and `as_index=False` with aggregation `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(['member_id','event_path'],sort=False,as_index=False)['event_duration'].sum()
print (df)
   member_id    event_path  event_duration
0        111        vk.com              34
1        111   twitter.com               4
2        111  facebook.com              56
3        222      vesti.ru               6
4        222  facebook.com              23
5        222        vk.com              76
6        333      avito.ru              12
7        444       mail.ru               7
8        444        vk.com              20
9        444     yandex.ru              40
```

Another possible solution is add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['member_id', 'event_path'],sort=False)['event_duration'].sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   member_id    event_path  event_duration
0        111        vk.com              34
1        111   twitter.com               4
2        111  facebook.com              56
3        222      vesti.ru               6
4        222  facebook.com              23
5        222        vk.com              76
6        333      avito.ru              12
7        444       mail.ru               7
8        444        vk.com              20
9        444     yandex.ru              40
```

---

Function [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) is used to add an aggregated calculation back to the original df as a new column.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is that you try to assign it to a column in the original dataframe. And since your new column has less rows than the original dataframe, it gets repeated at the end.